# Need guarantee that signals will be deilivered by offending thread

Tags: pthreads, clone, signals

I'm working on a project and cannot find any documentation that verifies signal/thread behavior for the following case.

I need to ensure that signals generated in a thread will be delivered by the offending thread (namely, `SIGSEGV`).  I've been *told* that POSIX doesn't ensure this behavior and that `pthreads`, for example, can generate signals in `pthread 1` yet have the signal delivered in `pthread 2`.  Therefore, I'm planning on using `clone(2)` to have finer control of signal/thread behavior, but still cannot find documentation in the man pages that ensures signals will be delivered by the offending thread.

Hardcore systems programmers: any documentation or insights would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [POSIX chapter on Signal Generation and Delivery](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) states that:

> At the time of generation, a
>   determination shall be made whether
>   the signal has been generated for the
>   process or for a specific thread
>   within the process. Signals which are
>   generated by some action attributable
>   to a particular thread, such as a
>   hardware fault, shall be generated for
>   the thread that caused the signal to
>   be generated. Signals that are
>   generated in association with a
>   process ID or process group ID or an
>   asynchronous event, such as terminal
>   activity, shall be generated for the
>   process.

A synchronous `SIGSEGV` caused by an incorrect memory access in a thread is clearly such a signal *"...generated by some action attributable to a particular thread..."*, so they are guaranteed to be generated for the offending thread (which means handled or ignored by that thread, as appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this works, even if it isn't guaranteed. I base this observation on the fact that I used to work at a company where we routinely handled SIGSEGV in multithreaded programs and printed a stack trace to a log file (based on currently location). We did this on a variety of platforms--windows, linux, tru64 unix, aix, hpux, sunos ... and maybe one or two others that I can't recall. This (usually!) works because the location of SIGSEGV is still on the current stack (the signal handling mechanism just adds a few call frames over top of it).

It's only fair to mention that there's very little that you should do in a signal handler because there aren't many functions that are async signal safe. We ignored this and mostly got away with it, except if I recall on sunos (or aix) where we would get burned--the process would occasionally (and seemingly randomly) hard exit inside the signal handler.

I believe the recommended approach is to NOT handle SIGSEGV, and let the process exit with a core dump so you can analyze later in a debugger.